# Conditional apply() in r

Tags: r, conditional-statements

I am struggling to create a variable based on a condition in my data frame.

I think the code is quite self-explanatory.

```
DT$xp_ratio_y<- apply(DT,1,function(x) 
     if(DT$driv_y_add_flg==1) {
     x=DT$driv_y_experience/DT$driv_y_age
     } else {
     x=0
     }
)
```

Comment: Your code is not self-explanatory at all. You `apply` a `function(x)` but do **not** use `x` in the function, you use 3 columns of the dataset `DT`. Those operations are likely to give vectors as a result. Also, is the condition in the `if` throwing an error?

Comment: Also if `DT$driv_y_add_flg` is a 0/1 value you can just multiply it to `DT$driv_y_experience/DT$driv_y_age` and get the x value directly without the if:
x=(DT$driv_y_experience/DT$driv_y_age) *  DT$driv_y_add_flg`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're making it too complicated. Just calculate for all then remove those you don't want:

```
DT$xp_ratio_y <- DT$driv_y_experience/DT$driv_y_age
DT$xp_ratio_y[DT$driv_y_add_flg !=1 ] <- 0
```